# Excel chart for 250 row values

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have 250 rows and 2 columns in my excel spreadsheet. Now, I want to create a chart that shows all values clearly. What kind of chart i should use for such big row values? I tried, clustered column chart, but that is not able to show all the row values.

The chart i get like below, but it doesn't show values clearly. i would like to know what alternate and perfect chart i should use for such huge row values? please advise

[image]

**Update screenshot with Pivot chart: (how to remove auto sorting of date field here?)**

I tried Pivot chart, it looks good. thanks for the suggestion. I have an issue with that. When i choose "date" and "new cases" for pivot chart, it is not taking values from the order i have given, instead it does sorting of dates and then draw the table and chart. I tried to remove sorting by following, "More Sort Options > Right Click ‘Pivot tables’ > Select ‘sort menu’ > select ‘More Options’ > deselect ‘Sort automatically", it didn't work. Please see the updated screenshot. Green values are my order, but red one's are automatically sorted, which i don't want.

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it lacks definition of requirements. 250 values are a lot, it might fit in a 25 x 10 matrix which almost fills up the screen, on any chart that will not be readable. Other workaround would be to generate pivot chart and filter data, but again not enough info for suggesting best way.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. People will likely not want to look at 250 values at once. What information are you trying to convey? This will help you focus the attention and perhaps aggregate or filter your data.

Comment: I am looking at pivot chart and filter, seems to be a good suggestion for my scenario.

Comment: I tried Pivot chart, it looks good. thanks for the suggestion. I have an issue with that. When i choose "date" and "new cases" for pivot chart, it is not taking values from the order i have given, instead it does sorting of dates and then draw the table and chart. I tried to remove sorting by following, "More Sort Options > Right Click ‘Pivot tables’ > Select ‘sort menu’ > select ‘More Options’ > deselect ‘Sort automatically", it didn't work. Please see the updated screenshot in my actual question.

Comment: You need to convert your date column into an actual Date to make it sort properly. Use `DATEVALUE` to convert a date stored as text to a Date. Then use the new column in your pivot table. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/datevalue-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252

Comment: Hi, I don't want to sort anything. I want to be same order how i provided, for ex: i want the pivot table and chart to be Oct 1 2020, Sep 30 2020, Sep 29 2020 like that.